# GetMatchingProductSample AMAZON API

Tags: api, amazon-mws

Im try to Get Product details with GetMatchingProductSample.php
request param look correctly:

```
    $request->setSellerId(MERCHANT_ID);
    $request->setMarketplaceId(my ID);
    $request->setASINList(my ASIN);
```

when i try to execute I receive always this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function _toQueryParameterArray() on a non-object
> I've look a method but I don't see any error

When I type `request->` I have only these methods:

- setASINlist setSellerId setMWSAuthToken

Comment: forgot to say
when i try using scratchpad with same parameter ..all work

Comment: Here ok i found why about my question.
Obviously they lacked the parameters and if someone can serve this is the correct call:

`code`
 $asins = array('B06Y16RL4W', 'B071DQ128D');

 $request = new 
 MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetMatchingProductRequest();

 $asin_list = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_ASINListType();
 $request->setSellerId(MERCHANT_ID);
 $request->setMarketplaceId(MARKETPLACE_ID);
 $asin_list->setASIN($asins);
 $request->setASINList($asin_list);
`code`

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found a way to do a right call.
Obviously they lacked the parameters and if someone can serve this is the correct call:

```
 $asins = array('B06Y16RL4W', 'B071DQ128D');
 $request = new 
 MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetMatchingProductRequest();
 $asin_list = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_ASINListType();
 $request->setSellerId(MERCHANT_ID);
 $request->setMarketplaceId(MARKETPLACE_ID);
 $asin_list->setASIN($asins);
 $request->setASINList($asin_list);
```